# How to link connected devices to a SQL database?

Tags: sql, networking, network-programming, nmap

Our project is about viewing LAN communications status information. Do you have any idea how I can send mac addresses of connected devices to a SQL database?

Answer (score 0):

There needs to be an application/tool which can read IP addresses from the network. Tools like Solarwinds or Angry IP Scanner can export the scanned IP addresses. You can also use terminal to get list of all IP addresses on the network. You can manually load this export or use integration tools such as Alteryx, Informatica etc. to load this exported file to SQL database.

Comment: I actually want to load the database automatically